# attaching an array to an event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, for-loop

```
var image = [];

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {         
    image[i]= Titanium.UI.createImageView({ 
        top: row,
        image: avatar                                
    });             
    win.add(image[i]);
}

image[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    alert('image number'+i);
});
```

im trying to attach an event to an array, but its saying object unidentfied! :)) whats wrong!!

Comment: Where is it saying object undefined?

Comment: Did you mean to have the `addEventListener` call outside of your for loop? As written, you are accessing an undefined element of your `image` array.

Comment: yeh i want outside, if put it inside it will assigned to the last element!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually no new solution, just a correction for @Mahesh Velaga's answer:

```
var image = [];
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {         
    image[i]= Titanium.UI.createImageView({ 
        top:row,                 
        image:avatar                                
    });             
    win.add(image[i]);

    (function(i) {  // -- added (inti)

        image[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            alert('image number'+i);
        });

    })(i);          // -- added (inti)
}
```

You need a closure around the eventListener for the `i` value to be local for its callback.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `i` is out of index

There is no `image[test.length]` and hence it throws the error (since i = test.length once the loop is exited)

**Edit**:

Try the following:

```
var image = [];
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {         
    image[i]= Titanium.UI.createImageView({ 
        top:row,                 
        image:avatar                                
    });             
    win.add(image[i]);
    setEventListner(i);
}

function setEventListener(index) {
    image[index].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
         alert('image number'+ index);
    });
}
```

Comment: The solution would appear to be to move the event listener attachment inside your loop...

Comment: yeh i want outside, if put it inside it will assigned to the last element!

Comment: what do you mean by "if put it inside it will assigned to the last element!" ? You are adding a different event listener to each image, if you put it inside the loop.

Comment: There is still a problem with this. The for loop does not create a closure, so the i variable inside the eventListener will be global, and will always say the last value it was given. This is pingpong's problem.